# Forming a select query in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

Sorry if this was asked before, but I can't get this to working. I just want to add a single quote to the start of a line and single quote and a comma at the end of the line in a file.

I'm trying to get something like this:

> select something from DBNAME where VALUE in ( 'ONE ',
>
> 'TWO ',
>
> 'THREE ',

But what I get is:

> select something from DBNAME where VALUE in ( 'ONE
>
> ',
>
> 'TWO
>
> ',
>
> 'THREE
>
> ',

This is my code:

```
echo "select something from DBNAME where VALUE in (" > /path/to/file.sql
sed 's/^/\x27/g; s/$/\x27,/g' /path/to/one/two/three/file.txt
cat /path/to/one/two/three/file.txt >> /path/to/file.sql
```

content of /path/to/one/two/three/file.txt is as you might have guessed:

> ONE
>
> TWO
>
> THREE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
ONE
TWO
THREE

$ awk '
    BEGIN { printf "select something from DBNAME where VALUE in (" }
    { print "\047" $0 "\047," }
' file
select something from DBNAME where VALUE in ('ONE',
'TWO',
'THREE',
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess there was also a problem with my "file". I ran a dos2unix on it and it helped.